# Reset a sub world in gazebo world

Tags: gazebo-all-versions

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Say I have a bunch of sub worlds in gazebo, is there any way to reset a particular sub world?

Here is what I mean, assuming I have 4 sub worlds in gazebo:

[image: image description]

How do I reset, say, sub world number 2 without resetting the other three?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27040/reset-a-sub-world-in-gazebo-world/) by [kolohe113](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28855/kolohe113/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Each world has its own control topic where you can publish to reset it.

For example (from the terminal):

```
gz world -w default -r
```

or

```
gz topic -p /gazebo/default/world_control -m "reset {all: true}"
```

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2021-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kolohe113](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28855/kolohe113/) on 2021-06-04**:
Thank you for answering! So there is a way to spawn multiple worlds in the same gazebo simulation?

**Comment by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) on 2021-06-04**:
https://community.gazebosim.org/t/use-case-of-multiple-worlds-in-an-sdf/375